# zsh: How do I set autocomplete so that it inserts the completion when cursor is between text?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, zsh, bash-completion

In my bash shell, when my cursor is between text, and I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it autocompletes the filename, and when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it inserts the completion at the cursor, and everything after the cursor remains, e.g.

```
  $ cp foo.ba¦r.baz.py 
             ^  <== cursor position
```

Hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, and now I see:

```
  $ cp foo.bar.baz.py¦r.baz.py
                     ^ <== cursor position
```

I like this behavior, particularly when doing a `mv` or `cp` and want to modify the original filename.  How can I get **zsh** to do the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **expand-or-complete-prefix**, adding this to your *.zshrc* file:

```
bindkey '^i' expand-or-complete-prefix
```

Read [this page](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide06.html) for more details about *zsh* completion.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted!  Thanks @esauvisky!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can add the `_prefix` control function at the end of your `zstyle ':completion:*' completer` command in your zshrc, so it will look something like this:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _force_rehash _complete _list _match _prefix
```

You also need to enable `completeinword` for this to work:

```
setopt completeinword
```

This way you aren't forced to use expansion like you would be by binding `expand-or-complete-prefix`.